# Python .exe containing alive progress bar error (FileNotFound)

Tags: python, windows, package, pyinstaller, executable

I converted my .py file which contains the alive progress bar package https://pypi.org/project/alive-progress/ into a .exe for windows using the pyinstaller command `pyinstaller --console` . I however receive an error when I run the program. It runs fine until the alive bar is called and then it prints out the error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "network_nodes_ping.py", line 38, in <module>
  File "alive_progress\core\progress.py", line 106, in alive_bar
  File "alive_progress\core\configuration.py", line 149, in create_context
  File "alive_progress\core\configuration.py", line 183, in lazy_init
  File "alive_progress\core\configuration.py", line 14, in _spinner_input_factory
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "alive_progress\styles\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "alive_progress\styles\exhibit.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "alive_progress\styles\internal.py", line 126, in <module>
  File "alive_progress\styles\internal.py", line 12, in create_spinners
  File "alive_progress\animations\spinners.py", line 43, in frame_spinner_factory
  File "alive_progress\animations\spinners.py", line 43, in <genexpr>
  File "alive_progress\animations\spinners.py", line 43, in <genexpr>
  File "alive_progress\utils\cells.py", line 145, in to_cells
  File "alive_progress\utils\cells.py", line 149, in split_graphemes
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "grapheme\__init.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "grapheme\api.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "grapheme\finder.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "grapheme\grapheme_property_group.py", line 97, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\BRYANV~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI85082\\grapheme\\data/grapheme_break_property.json'
[13328] Failed to execute script 'network_nodes_ping' due to unhandled exception!
```

Comment: If you read the bottom of the error it tells you what the problem is.  It can't find your json file

Comment: Why would you assume that's his JSON file? It's not. This is specifically an error that occurs when you attempt to create an executable in PyInstaller and you're using alive-progress.

This is some JSON file alive progress is trying to use in some way shape or form. So yeah, a JSON file is missing, but your comment doesn't exactly help.

Answer (score 4):

A shorter alternative to what [@Pluckerpluck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1189471/pluckerpluck) has suggested would be using `--collect-data grapheme` instead of `--add-data <...>`.

Answer (score 1):

`alive-progress` uses a library called `grapheme`. This library requires a JSON file which you will have to manually specify when using PyInstaller.

In my case, I had it under `.venv` so the command to make this work was:

```
pyinstaller -F --add-data ".\.venv\Lib\site-packages\grapheme\data\grapheme_break_property.json;grapheme\data" my_file.py
```

Note that the argument `--add-data` takes both a source and a target directory (which we set to `grapheme\data`)

I will warn you however, that the default terminal doesn't have the fonts capable of actually displaying the progress bar. It works, but it doesn't look pretty. If you run the `.exe` from a proper terminal though with the font support, it works just fine after this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .spec file to generate exe - it's similar to what @Pluckerpluck said but you would need to include this file like this

```
datas=[(r"C:\Source\venv\Lib\site-packages\grapheme", "grapheme/")]
```

If you add this in your .spec file. It works.